# Python - opencv - motion detection - extract contour result to file or function

Tags: python, opencv, detection, motion

I have OpenCV motion tracking working, but I'd like Python to extract an image of whatever is inside the contours on motion detection for use within the program or as an image write.

Code so far:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

from windowcapture import WindowCapture

wincap = WindowCapture('your window here')

frame1 = wincap.get_screenshot()
frame2 = wincap.get_screenshot()

while(True):

    diff = cv2.absdiff(frame1, frame2)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=3)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    cv2.drawContours(frame1, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("window", frame1)
    frame1 = frame2
    frame2 = wincap.get_screenshot()

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I couldn't find a ```windowcapture ``` package in ```pip``` so I won't write a normal answer, but I can help. You can take your contour and fill it using ```cv2.floodfill``` then just use ```cv2.bitwise_and``` with mask as filled contour and frame as src. And then you will get the image inside your contour.

Answer (score 0):

This function could help you. It calculates the bounding box region of a contour and crops it from the image.

```
def get_sub_images(image, contours):
    """
    Crop images according to the contour bounding boxes and return them in a
    list.

    Args:
        image: numpy.ndarray
        contours: list

    Returns:
        list
    """
    sub_images = []
    for cnt in contours:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        sub_image = image[slice(y, y+h), slice(x, x+w)]
        sub_images.append(sub_image)
    return sub_images
```